# Using single shader for texturing points and triangles openGL ES 2

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

As far as i can tell to map a point you use

```
gl_FragColor =  texture2D(Texture, gl_PointCoord);
```

And to map a triangle

```
gl_FragColor =  texture2D(Texture, TexCoorFromVertexShader);
```

So if i want to us both - points and triangles how do i handle it. So far I'm thinking about having multiple programs and switching them depending on what am i drawing but that seems like a lot of overhead. Or is that just how things work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct, separate shaders are the way to go. Multiple `if` statements inside a single GLSL program can be very expensive. In your case, I can bet they're a real performance hit since the lookup would be done per-vertex.

Have a read here for further info: [Shader branching question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176247/shader-branching-question)

Comment: I was hoping more people would share their thoughts on the topic but obviously opengl is not as popular as jquery... Hours of googling didn't result in better suggestions so i guess you're right.

Comment: OpenGl ES is new to the game, but will be growing a lot thanks to AR, games, interactive video/photography - so the learning resources will improve too. If I find more information on this subject with better references I will update my post and let you know.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/15344430/… can you please have a look at this link and help me over this. I also need some documentation for your code.